# iOS - UITabBar glitches on showing starting iOS 12.1

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

UITabBar glitches and items jump down while moving between UIViewController..

Imagine a Controller has the value hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true and it pops back to the root view controller which has the value hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false, the UITabBar behaves differently with a glitch before showing in it's original position.

N.B: Issue only happens starting iOS 12.1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take your time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking new questions.

Comment: I believe this is a known issue and has been posted on here a number of times already